# Unusual for loop found in library

Tags: python

I'm analyzing the code of this [library](https://github.com/eerimoq/cantools/blob/master/cantools/database/utils.py) and stumbled upon something unsusual in the `decode_data` function.

```
def decode_data(data, fields, formats, decode_choices, scaling):
    unpacked = formats.big_endian.unpack(bytes(data))
    unpacked.update(formats.little_endian.unpack(bytes(data[::-1])))

    return {
        field.name: _decode_field(field,
                                  unpacked[field.name],
                                  decode_choices,
                                  scaling)
        for field in fields
    }
```

More precisely, I do not understand the syntax of the return statement:

```
return {
        field.name: _decode_field(field,
                                  unpacked[field.name],
                                  decode_choices,
                                  scaling)
        for field in fields
    }
```

It looks to me like a reverse for loop, but I've never seen a similar notation elsewhere.

Also `field.name:` written with the colon at the end does not make sense to me.

I know of lambda functions that use the colon notation, but the missing lambda statement points to something else.

Can someone explain to me what is going on here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

Comment: Looks like a dictionary comprehension, but made easier to read.

Comment: its a dict comprehension, similar to :`x = [1,2,3,4,5]` then `{i: str(i) for i in x}`

Comment: `field.name` means that `field` is an object with a `name` attribute.

Comment: Refer to dataclass.field - https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

Comment: cool stuff, thank you all.